# iPhone USB Tethering disconnects affter a few seconds on Mint 21.2

Tags: linux-mint, iphone

The title says it all really:

I'm running Mint 21.2 Cinnamon and am trying to connect to the internet using an iPhone over USB. It worked fine during the installation of Mint when it was run from a LiveCD (USB). Now that I have Mint installed permanently, it does connect to the internet, but seems to fade/error out after a couple pings:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=30.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=25.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=27.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=26.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=115 time=23.7 ms
<Radio silence>
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 8 received, 42.8571% packet loss, time 13139ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.476/25.673/30.322/2.578 ms
```

I tried googling the issue, but running commands like
`sudo systemctl enable ModemManager.service` or disabling automounting of the iPhone file system did not seem to help.